# Forks/ alternative coins and paper wallets

Tags: paper-wallet, coldstorage

So I have some bitcoin on paper wallets purchased at ATMs  well prior to the bitcoin cash split. I have only kept cold-storage paper thus far, but recently purchased a Ledger Nano S. My question is, with the forks of BC cash and the coming BC gold, am I missing out on these "matching funds" from the forks by not having these coins sitting in an exchange or online wallet?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can, at any time you want, import those private keys into a Bitcoin Cash or Bitcoin Gold client and move those coins. You control the private keys, so you control those coins so long as the networks that they are on are still functional.